# while loop (Python) becomes slow after 500 cycle in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, while-loop, raspberry-pi4, slowdown

I am making one project with analog sensors using a raspberry pi 4 controller (4GB ram). I have connected 9 sensors currently, I am using while loop for an infinite cycle. The code is very simple taking input from sensors and using the canvas library changing the colour of shapes when it gets pressed and remains the same when not. The problem is after 500-550 cycles it is getting slower. As the number of cycles increases the response rate becomes slower and slower. Can anyone please suggest how can I overcome this problem?

I am also a noob in coding so please guide me if I did some mistake. I am writing code for only one sensor because it is the same for all the sensors.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import Rpi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import tkinter as tk


GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
.
.
.
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

root=tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='white', width=500, height=500)
canvas.grid()

canvas.bind('<key>', lambda event: root.destroy() if (event.char == 'q') else 0)

while True:
    def sense1(on):
        square1= canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 105, 105, width=0, fill='red' if on else 'green')
    .
    .
    .
    def sense9(on):
        square9= canvas.create_rectangle(235, 235, 335, 335, width=0, fill='red' if on else 'green')

    global S1,...,S9

    if GPIO.input(7) == GPIO.HIGH:
        S1 = sense1(True)
    else:
        S1 = sense1(False)
    .
    .
    .
    if GPIO.input(18) == GPIO.HIGH:
        S9 = sense9(True)
    else:
        S9 = sense9(False)

    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
```

same code I have written for the other 8 sensors.

Comment: If the code is simple, please include it. There may be things happening within your loop that are causing it. Without any code it is difficult to tell. At the very least, please include the relevant sections.

Comment: for every loop, you're creating a new rectangle for every sensor.  In a limited environment such as a Pi, I'm wondering if it would make it easier if you'd just create the necessary rectangles ahead of time and modify the rectangle attributes as you see fit.

Comment: Actually this is just for testing purposes. In actual work, I have to connect 150+ sensors, and that time I am thinking to take output in ready software. @ewong

Comment: and you mean only this canvas rectangles are bothering for the program?

Answer (score 0):

Check core temperature.
The while loop can cause the temperature of the microprocessor to rise. The raspberry has a self-protection mechanism that is activated when the core temperature is very high, generating a drop in performance. I suggest you change the while loop to callbacks

Saludos!